# Panache MongoDB: Return only matching data from Array

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Is it possible to apply a filter on the Entity in order to filter the following collection entry, based on the lang property within descriptions and subTypes.descriptions?

```
{
    "id": "609a85120c133e33e4cc3ed7",
    "code": "REST",
    "descriptions": [
        {
            "lang": "pt",
            "description": "Restaurante"
        },
        {
            "lang": "en",
            "description": "Restaurant"
        }
    ],
    "subTypes": [
        {
            "code": "TIP",
            "descriptions": [
                {
                    "lang": "pt",
                    "description": "Restaurante Tipico"
                },
                {
                    "lang": "en",
                    "description": "Typical Restaurante"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "code": "HMB",
            "descriptions": [
                {
                    "lang": "pt",
                    "description": "Restaurante Hamburger"
                },
                {
                    "lang": "en",
                    "description": "Burger"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to apply the query on the list method from PanacheMongoEntity. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any query possible on MongoDB on the `list` method of PanacheMongoEntity via a native MongoDB query (so a standard JSON query).

MongoDB allow to [query an array of document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/), and support [projection on the array element](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-specific-array-elements-in-the-returned-array).

MongoDB with Panache projection via the `find().project()` method only works with field projection so you'll need to use a native MongoDB query directly on the collection, you will not be able to use the `list` method.

Something like this should work:

```
Entity.mongoCollection().find("{//your query}", "{subTypes.descriptions:{$elemMatch: {lang:'en'}}}");
```

Comment: very useful. I've actually ending up refactoring some additional implementations following this suggestion. Thanks